# Ms-Word Mail Merging format

Tags: ms-word, formatting, mailmerge

I'm using MS-Office 2016 to do a Mail Merging for a contract where the original Data is stored in an Excel file.

I have problem formating the Plate number as it should be in a format like

this `##-#####` and that's how it's shown in Excel, However, when i do the merge it shows like

this `#####-##`  and here is a photo to show exactly one entry.

[image: Example Of the Problem]

I tried placing the merged field out of the table, tweaked with right to left, left to right and tried to generate a format based on what i saw on the internet about formatting Date and Currency, However, I got no positive results.

I would appreciate if you could help me formatting this field or direct me to reference in which i can learn how this formatting thing works.

Or, I don't know if this viable but every time i open the .docx file it says that it need to run sql query, can I access that query?, I think I have a base knowledge about that and I may be able to format it through the query.

Comment: Yours is an end-user issue, not a programming issue and, as such, should be posted in an end-user forum, not at StackOverflow. That said, you may be able to get the desired results with a field coded as: {QUOTE{SET ID "{MERGEFIELD Data}-0"}{SET EXP1{=-{=-{ID}-ID}/2}}{SET EXP2{=-({ID}*(-1)-{ID})/2}}"{=EXP2 \# 00}-{=EXP1 \# 00000}"}, where 'Data' is your field name. THE SQL prompt is normal behaviour for a mailmerge.

Comment: This looks like an issue with RTL/LTR since it's also reversing the content before/after the hyphen. As Paul said, an end-user venue might have more experience with this kind of problem. The message about the query is a standard *security* message, but you can see the query. In the Immediate Window, for example, the combinatino of: `?ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ConnectString` and `?ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.QueryString` should show you that. You can set `QueryString` using VBA code but you're limited to 256 characters, as I recall.